# CSS stretch textbox to fill remaining space

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a label and a textbox and I simply want the textbox to stretch out to fill the remaining space on the page.  I know that the 100% width doesn’t include any padding or margin values so I’ve added that to textbox and div. I’ve searched many similar topics, but my textbox always drops to a new line below the label.  What am I missing?  I'm placing my css inline just for testing purposes.

```
<div style="padding-right:10px;">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" style="float:left; width:150px; display:inline-block"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="display:inline-block; width:100%; padding-right:0"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of: [CSS make textbox fill all available width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193880/css-make-textbox-fill-all-available-width)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS make textbox fill all available width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193880/css-make-textbox-fill-all-available-width)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`calc()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) + `box-sizing: border-box;` for known width label.

```css
.container label,
.container input[type="text"] {
  float: left;
}
.container label {
  width: 150px;
}
.container input[type="text"] {
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>Label Example</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Or, use [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), that makes it very easy also works for dynamic width.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.container input[type="text"] {
  flex: 1; /*take all the available space*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>Label Example</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

If you need to support legacy browsers, try using CSS table. Note, to make it work I added a span tag around the input box.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.container label,
.container span {
  display: table-cell;
}
.container label {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.container span {
  width: 100%;
}
.container input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <label>Label Example</label>
  <span><input type="text"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: `flex: 1` is a new one on me, but it certainly does the job!