# Stretch the input field to the remaining space using flex in an ordered list

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-lists

I'm working on a form with an ordered list. Each `<li>` has a `<label>` and an `<input>` field. I put two list items on a single line using `float` but I cant fill the space between them with the `input` field. Have a look:
[image]

Tried using `flex` with inline-formatting but it won't work. Also, can't use `box-sizing: border-box;` property because the numbering of the list disappears.
Tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883998/css-stretch-textbox-to-fill-remaining-space) (not the first part because can't use JavaScript) but it doesn't help. What should I do?
Here's the code:

```html
<ol>
    <li style="float: left;"><b>
      <label>NIC.#: </label>
      <input type="text" name="nic">
    </b></li>
    <li style="float: right;"><b>
      <label>DOB: </label>
      <input type="DOB" name="bday">
    </b></li>
    <br><br>
    <li style="float: left;"><b>
      <label>Email: </label>
      <input type="email" name="e-mail">
    </b></li>
    <li style="float: right;"><b>Gender 
      <input type="radio" name="gen">
      <label>Male</label>
      <input type="radio" name="gen">
      <label>Female</label>
    </b></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Show us your css. HTML doesn't say anything here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it by using display flex and width property,

```css
ol {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0;
}

ol li {
    margin: 15px;
    width: calc(50% - 30px);

}

input {
    width: 100%;
}

b {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li><b>
      <label>NIC.#: </label>
      <input type="text" name="nic">
    </b></li>
    <li><b>
      <label>DOB: </label>
      <input type="DOB" name="bday">
    </b></li>
    <li><b>
      <label>Email: </label>
      <input type="email" name="e-mail">
    </b></li>
    <li><b>Gender 
      <input type="radio" name="gen">
      <label>Male</label>
      <input type="radio" name="gen">
      <label>Female</label>
    </b></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: this looks good but what if i have more list items of `width: 100%;` above these ones; as u can see in the screenshot these items are only 6,7,8 and 9. If i put the wrap on `<ol>` it will wrap the others too which i dont want

Comment: You can instead add all this elements in a div and wrap them, and the you can give display:flex; and flex-wrap: wrap; for the div which you are going to wrap the <li>'s